# How can i do a javascript timer that show div at the end of the timer for few second and repeat it

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, intervals, clock

I added my code that I am using (based on other question here)

for now it is not works for me because there is no sync between the interval and the div

I tried without success these steps : 60 sec timer starting,

after 60 sec the clock will be remove and other div will show,
 and after 3 second that the new div shown the clock will start again(and the second div will disappear  and ... etc

Thank you

```
    $("#div1").hide();

        var count=5;

        var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

        function timer()
        {
          count=count-1;

          if (count <= 0)
          {
            clearInterval(counter);
                $("#div1").fadeIn("slow");
                $("#div1").delay(3000).fadeOut("slow");
                myTimeoutFunction();

             count = 5;
             //counter ended, do something here
             // return;
          }
            console.log(count);
          //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
        }

        function myTimeoutFunction()
        {
            console.log("test");

        }




       });

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div id="div1">
 3
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`counter` not appear rest after calling `clearTimeout(counter)`

Try chaining `.delay()` to `.fadeIn()` , using `complete` callback of `.fadeOut()` to reset `count` ,  `counter` , call `MyTimeoutFunction`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div1">
    3
  </div>
  <script>
    $("#div1").hide();

    var count = 5;

    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);

    function timer() {
      count = count - 1;

      if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        $("#div1").fadeIn("slow")
          .delay(3000).fadeOut("slow", function() {
            count = 5;
            myTimeoutFunction();
            counter = setInterval(timer, 1000);
          });


        //counter ended, do something here
        // return;
      }
      console.log(count);
      //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
    }

    function myTimeoutFunction() {
      console.log("test");

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding :

- 1 second ticker.
- Every 5 ticks, stop the ticker, perform an *animation-delay-animation* sequence, then restart the ticker.
- Do something at a certain point in the cycle.

The basic *animation-delay-animation* sequence can be coded as :

```
$("#div1").fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow')
```

However, the interesting part of the problem is to "do something at a certain point in the cycle" as the cycle affords several cardinal points at which something might be done, not just the one indicated in the question. To this end, you might choose to implement the *animation-delay-animation* sequence as a promise chain, in which the sequence is split into its individual components, giving access to the cardinal points.

jQuery's `.promise()` method makes writing a promise chain very simple.

The following code affords a comprehensive set of opportunities to "do something" :

```
var $div1 = $('#div1').hide(),
    count, counter;
function startTicker() {
    // Start of a fresh 5 second countdown - possibly do something here.
    count = 5;
    counter = setInterval(ticker, 1000);
}
function ticker() {
    if (--count <= 0) {
        // Counter ended
        clearInterval(counter);
        doAsynchronousStuff().then(startTicker);
    }
    // Do code for showing the number of seconds here.
}
function doAsynchronousStuff() {
    // Before fadeIn starts - possibly do something here.
    return $div1.fadeIn('slow').promise()
    .then(function() {
        // After fadeIn completes but before delay starts - possibly do something here.
        return $div1.delay(3000).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        // After delay but before fadeOut starts - possibly do something here.
        return $div1.fadeOut('slow').promise();
    });
}

startTicker(); // start the cycle
```

*Other approaches exist, but a promise chain avoids deep nesting of callback functions.*

To make `ticker()` clearer, the asynchronous tasks appear in a separate function `doAsynchronousStuff()`, which returns a promise to `ticker()`. Thus `ticker()` is able to execute `doAsynchronousStuff().then(startTicker)`, ie call `doAsynchronousStuff()` and start another cycle on completion of all the asynchronous tasks.